# What is root an non root user in docker containers and how it really affect security?

Tags: linux, docker, security, unix

I am reading a book in **freecodecamp** that talks about **docker**, the section i read is talking about creating Javascript images which utilize node as the base image and the `user` instructions that sets the default user to `node`

The author mentioned that `user` instruction is set to `node` for security issue so it's a better idea to run as a non-root user whenever possible

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

EXPOSE 3000

USER node

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

I can't understand two points there:

1 - **What is root and non-root user for an image??**

2 - **What security issue that instruction protect from ???**

Comment: [unix.se] is more appropriate for questions that aren't strictly about programming as such. There's also [security.se]. Your first question is a better fit for the former (indeed, certainly already asked and answered), and the second for the latter.

Comment: (It's not just a specific security issue but rather a class of them -- the point of not running as root even in a container could be fairly described as constraining attack surface, to reduce the number of yet-to-be-discovered security bugs that can be applied without a separate privilege escalation attack also included in the chain).

Comment: @Charles Duffy

will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general answer which applies to all possible Docker containers, but a very typical and common arrangement is that your base container only contains the `root` user.

What you can do then is to run [`adduser`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/8/adduser/) (on Debian-based platforms; or look at the more primitive [`useradd`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/useradd.8.html) utility and associated utilities like `groupadd` and `chsh` etc) to create a new regular user.

Of course, if the container is already set up with a regular non-root user account, you only need to specify that account name in the `Dockerfile` with the `USER` keyword, like in your question.

The risks of running everything as `root` are well-documented; you don't want a simple user script you created yourself to be able to erase system files by mistake, for example. If the script runs a service which exposes it to the big bad Internet, you *definitely* don't want an intruder who finds a way to exploit your script to trivially obtain `root` access immediately. Perhaps search for *principle of least privilege* for more background. See, for example, [Wikipedia's exposition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)